# How to use the Google Managed Certificate for GKE Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, gke-networking

I have the https being generated for frontend https for flytime.io (cloud run)
[image]

Now I want to use this for https support for backend (multi-ingress gke autopilot), from the following manual, intended to used the api.flytime.io domain:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/multi-cluster-ingress#https_support

[image]

But how should I configure the PATH_TO_KEYFILE and PATH_TO_CERTFILE with the manual (or there are other ways to do that)? If using the Google managed certification is not possible (why?), how do I generate a certificate for host name of api.flytime.io and get  PATH_TO_KEYFILE and PATH_TO_CERTFILE?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using GKE managed certificates, you don't use the `secret` method for setting up SSL in your Ingress. You have to create a `ManagedCertificate` object and then use the object's name in your Ingress in the `networking.gke.io/managed-certificates` annotation.

Here's an example. First, create the `ManagedCertificate` object.

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: managed-cert
spec:
  domains:
    - DOMAIN_NAME1 #<===== must be valid a domain you are owning
```

Now, reference this in your `Ingress` as follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: managed-cert-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: ADDRESS_NAME
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: managed-cert #<=== HERE IS YOUR CERT
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: mc-service
      port:
        number: SERVICE_PORT
```

You can find more information on [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs) docs page.